# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, virtualenv

How to Install opencv using conda with python3.7 on ubuntu 18.04?

I am following [this](https://pydeeplearning.com/opencv/install-opencv3-with-anaconda-python3-6-on-ubuntu-18-04/) link and others, but getting the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other
```

I have seen a comment somewhere that it is because the latest version of conda has python3.7 while the latest version of opencv is not compatible with it.

I am new to conda and not sure if that is the reason.

Any help?

Comment: Can you include the "specifications" (as hinted by "following") in the message?

Comment: try pip install instead